# Oracle XE 18c rename SID

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe-18.4

It is possible in Oracle 18c to rename the default sid (XE) in a custom SID?
I tryed using Oracle Database Configuration Assistant but having not success.
how can i possibly do?
Thanks

Comment: XE isn't designed to allow that.  You probably can, but you almost certainly shouldn't.  What is the problem with a sid of XE?

Comment: I have to migrate from a version 11 where the sid was called differently. Keeping XE I would have to modify several clients

Comment: You shouldn’t be using the SID in your connection strings anyway, you should be using the service name. If you are using XE edition then your user PDB will have a service name of XEPDB1, possibly with a domain.